# Object has no method push

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm querying some objects and I'm trying to put them in an array:

```
 var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')
  var query = new Parse.Query(Post)
  query.find({
    success: function (results) {
      console.log('Successfully retrieved ' + results.length + ' scores.')
      var arr = []
      results.forEach(function (result) {
        arr = arr.push(result.get('title'))
      })
      console.log(arr)
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert('Error: ' + error.code + ' ' + error.message)
    }
  })
```

as you can see `arr` is an array, but I don't know why I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'push'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong since `result.get('title')` get the correct String titles.

Comment: what are you try to accomplish with `arr.push(result.get('title'))` ? Why using another array instead of just map the one you already have?

Comment: `var arr = results.map(function(result) { return result.get("title"); });` would probably be easier to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, so after the assignment, `arr` is now a `Number` object.

You want to push onto the array like this:

```
results.forEach(function (result) {
    arr.push(result.get('title'))
})
```

Comment: Hey, you're right. But why, why `push` was returning a number?

Comment: because `Array.prototype.push` returns a `Number` object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Weird, `console.log` returns the array but using `return` returns nothing.

Comment: If it worked by returning an entire new array that would be so expensive

Comment: @Thomas So what do you suggest I do instead?

Comment: @alexchenco this anwer is perfect. But IF it worked like ` arr = arr.push(result.get('title'))` the object would be copied in every iteration. That would cost loads of memory. Now it works with the same object in every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer here says, `push()` does not return an array, but a `Number` object.  However, here is an alternative answer in case you'd prefer it.

```
var arr = results.map(function(result) {
    return result.get("title");
});
```

This function actually **does** return the array as the result, which seems like what you were after.